Is the belief of Durga visiting her "parental home" during the festival of Bengali Durga Puja mentioned in any scriptures?
These are some of the differences I managed to find between Navratri and Bengali Durga Puja. Please don't hesitate to correct me if you find any errors.
Navratri celebrates the mythological 10-day cosmic battle between Durga and Mahisasura, which is mentioned in texts like Devi Mahatmyam (part of Markandeya Purana). On the 10th day, she triumphs over evil.
On the other hand, in the Bengali tradition, it is believed that on the first day of the moon's waxing phase (in the month of Ashwina, which falls around September-October) i.e. on the day of Mahalaya, Durga starts her journey from her heavenly abode of Kailash to Earth, not to wage a war with Mahisasura, but to visit her parental home. And this Bengali tradition of Durga's trip to her earthly parental home is not mentioned in any Hindu scriptures, but it was made up by the people of Bengal centuries ago when the first Durga Puja in Bengal was celebrated. This is the only major difference I found between Navratri and Bengali Durga Puja.
Do you think this information is correct? Is the belief of Durga going for a trip to her parental home (which is accepted by all Bengalis) merely made up by the people of Bengal? Or is it actually mentioned in the scriptures?
My questions are only out of curiosity and a desire to gain accurate knowledge, and are not intended to offend any group of people.
Thank you.
